# Use the RewriteEngine to direct away from a denied directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, permissions

### The setup

- root/

  - .htaccess :

    ```
    Deny from All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule secret.txt /root/public/welcome.txt
    ```
  - secret.txt
  - public/

    - .htaccess :

      ```
      Allow from All
      ```
    - welcome.txt

### The problem

A request to `/root/secret.txt` results in a 403 (Forbidden) response that tells me I have no access to `/root/secret.txt`. (A direct request to `/root/public/welcome.txt` is permitted.)

Thus, it seems to me that the `RewriteEngine` *does nothing* to a request that would be denied by a `Deny from All` directive.

### The question

It would be nice if someone knows a way to get the expected `/root/public/welcome.txt` served. However, it would be nicer if someone could help me reach my eventual goal.

### The goal

I decided to write down my eventual goal, because maybe I'm just looking in the wrong direction.

I would like to `Deny from All` in the root, and have subdirectories decide when to override that with an `Allow`. Then I would also like Apache to rewrite all requests *that would result in a 403 or 404* to a single specific file. As of yet, I'm planning to do this with a `!-U` flag, but I can't get past my initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo may try this in the .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Deny from All

ErrorDocument 404 /Error403_404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /Error403_404.php
```

"Error403_404.php" is an example. Replace with the 403 and 404 error handler script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm afraid though, that you misinterpreted part of my question. In my example - public/welcome.php would be the specific file I want 404 and 403's to redirect to. However, your answer did introduce me to the ErrorDocument directive. I will play around a bit with that. I'll let you know. :)

Comment: You don't mention the error file in your question. But if that's the only problem, just replace `Error403_404.php` with `welcome.php`. Let me know if there is something else.

Comment: If you remove all the lines between the `Deny` directive and the `ErrorDocument` directive. The answer is perfectly sufficient. I was indeed looking in the wrong direction, I don't even need the `RewriteEngine`! :)

Comment: Updated. Glad you found out the way to do it.